# Making sure nobody (but the add-in) can access a list

Tags: list, permissions, csom, provider-hosted-app

I create Lists inside the app-web of a provider-hosted-app(-addin) using CSOM:
All access to that lists should only be done by the addin itself and not by the user. So I want to make sure nobody can access these Lists even if they know the address to them (and even if the permissions allow them to access "normal" Lists inside the SharePoint). - It's ok if administrators can access those lists

I create the Lists the following simple way:

```
ListCreationInformation listCreationInfo = new ListCreationInformation();
listCreationInfo.Title = ListName;
List newList = web.Lists.Add(listCreationInfo);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: You can consider giving Unique permissions to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Things you could try:

1. Hide the list (set .Hidden = true), but users with the link will be able to access it, or
2. Hide the list view web part, or
3. Hide the items of the list (add a filter in the default view and then create new personal views), or
4. Add an automatic redirection script if current user is not a member of group X, or
   any combination of the above...

Comment: This is provider hosted app using csom. There is no web part